# Mocking the Kotlin SupabaseClient for unit testing

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, supabase, supabase-database

TLDR : [Here is a minimally reproduceable example](https://github.com/jlengrand/supabase-mock-demo-kotlin). You do not need a Supabase account / database to get the error.

I have some code like this, which performs some simple transformation of data before saving it in [Supabase](https://supabase.com/)

```
    suspend fun saveClones(owner: String, repository: String, clones: GitHubClones): List<ResultClone> {
        val zeClones = clones.clones.map {
            Clone(
                owner = owner,
                repository = repository,
                count = it.count,
                uniques = it.uniques,
                timestamp = it.timestamp
            )
        }

        return client.postgrest["clone"].insert(zeClones, upsert = true, onConflict = "owner, repository, timestamp").decodeList<ResultClone>()
    }
```

I'd like to check that the data going in the insert call is what I expect it to be.
I've tried to mock the client using [mockk](https://mockk.io/) as such

```
val supabaseClient = mockk<SupabaseClient>()
val postgrest = mockk<Postgrest>()
val postgrestBuilder = mockk<PostgrestBuilder>()
val postgrestResult = PostgrestResult(body = null, headers = Headers.Empty)

every { supabaseClient.postgrest } returns postgrest
every { postgrest["path"] } returns postgrestBuilder
coEvery { postgrestBuilder.insert(values = any<List<Path>>()) } returns postgrestResult
```

but when running my test, I am facing the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Plugin rest not installed or not of type Postgrest. Consider installing Postgrest within your supabase client builder
    at io.github.jan.supabase.postgrest.PostgrestKt.getPostgrest(Postgrest.kt:172)
    at nl.lengrand.GitHubTrafficStoreTest$setUp$1.invoke(GitHubTrafficStoreTest.kt:53)
    at nl.lengrand.GitHubTrafficStoreTest$setUp$1.invoke(GitHubTrafficStoreTest.kt:53)
```

What would be the correct way to unit test that function? It looks like I also cannot really use test containers with Supabase, making integration tests equally as difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back here just to mentioned that I decided to go another direction, which I'm pretty satisfied with actually. I created a simple Docker Compose setup that I run with test containers and which simulate a simple Supabase instance. No need for mocking any more. It's more "integration tests" than "unit tests" at that point though.

[The full blog about it](https://lengrand.fr/unit-testing-supabase-in-kotlin/), but in short :

```
version: '3'

# Thanks https://github.com/mattddowney/compose-postgrest/blob/master/README.md
services:

  ################
  # postgrest-db #
  ################
  postgrest-db:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - DB_SCHEMA=${DB_SCHEMA}
    volumes:
      - "./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    networks:
      - postgrest-backend
    restart: always

  #############
  # postgrest #
  #############
  postgrest:
    image: postgrest/postgrest:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - PGRST_DB_URI=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgrest-db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      - PGRST_DB_SCHEMA=${DB_SCHEMA}
      - PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE=${DB_ANON_ROLE}
      - PGRST_JWT_SECRET=${PGRST_JWT_SECRET}
    networks:
      - postgrest-backend
    restart: always

  #############
  # Nginx     #
  #############
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - postgrest-backend

networks:
  postgrest-backend:
    driver: bridge
```

and the test file :

```
import io.github.jan.supabase.SupabaseClient
import io.github.jan.supabase.createSupabaseClient
import io.github.jan.supabase.postgrest.Postgrest
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.testcontainers.containers.ComposeContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
import java.io.File

@Testcontainers
class MainKtTestTestContainers {

    // The jwt token is calculated manually (https://jwt.io/) based on the private key in the docker-compose.yml file, and a payload of {"role":"postgres"} to match the user in the database
    private val jwtToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoicG9zdGdyZXMifQ.88jCdmcEuy2McbdwKPmuazNRD-dyD65WYeKIONDXlxg"

    private lateinit var supabaseClient: SupabaseClient

    @Container
    var environment: ComposeContainer =
        ComposeContainer(File("src/test/resources/docker-compose.yml"))
            .withExposedService("postgrest-db", 5432)
            .withExposedService("postgrest", 3000)
            .withExposedService("nginx", 80)

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        val fakeSupabaseUrl = environment.getServiceHost("nginx", 80) +
                ":" + environment.getServicePort("nginx", 80)

        supabaseClient = createSupabaseClient(
            supabaseUrl = "http://$fakeSupabaseUrl",
            supabaseKey = jwtToken
        ) {
            install(Postgrest)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testEmptyPersonTable(){
        runBlocking {
            val result = getPerson(supabaseClient)
            assertEquals(0, result.size)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testSavePersonAndRetrieve(){
        val randomPersons = listOf(Person("Jan", 30), Person("Jane", 42))

        runBlocking {
            val result = savePerson(randomPersons, supabaseClient)
            assertEquals(2, result.size)
            assertEquals(randomPersons, result.map { it.toPerson() })

            val fetchResult = getPerson(supabaseClient)
            assertEquals(2, fetchResult.size)
            assertEquals(randomPersons, fetchResult.map { it.toPerson() })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that extension properties can't be mocked like that.

My interpretation of extension property is, that it is in byte code present as static getter (basically same principe how extension functions are implemented), which 1st arugment is instance of "extended" type. And in Kotlin is such getter visible as property. That is why `mockStatic` should do the job.

When I modify code

```
@BeforeTest
fun setUp() {
  mockkStatic(SupabaseClient::postgrest)
  every { supabaseClient.postgrest } returns postgrest
}

@AfterTest
fun tearDown() {
  unmockkStatic(SupabaseClient::postgrest)
}
```

I got new error

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Person' is not found.
Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.common.kt:92)
```

so I would say, that this approach would work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the complete test class? When trying your code I'm getting another kind of error :) (io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for Postgrest(#2).get(person) among the configured answers: ()
)

Comment: Code https://github.com/jlengrand/supabase-mock-demo-kotlin/compare/main...stengvac:supabase-mock-demo-kotlin:mocking_extension_prop

error is from mocking `postgrestBuilder.insert` which is inline fun and it seems, that mock inline fun is not possible - see comment in code. But wrapping client to some class, with normal fun could help. Not clean, but there are boundaries as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As Vaclav mentioned in the accepted answer, part of the construction can be mocked statically, but we end up having to mock an inline function, which is impossible.

This makes the current setup not testable as such. I worked around the issue by wrapping the SupabaseClient inside a class, and I mock this class instead.

It creates more work, but I guess it is also cleaner from an architecture perspective in a certain way.

You can find the code [over here](https://github.com/jlengrand/supabase-mock-demo-kotlin/pull/1) .

But essentially I wrap the class like this

```
class DatabaseClient(private val client: SupabaseClient){

    suspend fun savePersons(persons: List<Person>): List<ResultPerson> {
        return client
            .postgrest["person"]
            .insert(persons)
            .decodeList<ResultPerson>()
    }
}
```

and then test like this

```
class MainKtTest{

    private lateinit var client : DatabaseClient

    @BeforeTest
    fun setUp() {

        client = mockk<DatabaseClient>()
        coEvery { client.savePersons(any<List<Person>>()) } returns listOf()
    }

    @Test
    fun testSavePerson(){

        val fakePersons = listOf(Person("name_1", 1), Person("name_2", 2))

        runBlocking {
            val result = savePerson(fakePersons, client)
            assertEquals(2, result.size)
        }
    }

}
```